# Ubuntu won't reboot after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, reboot, settings

I have tried upgrading ubuntu but since then my computer has been glitching, settings basically never respond and what worries me most : can't turn my computer off normally.

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 and am trying to update to 20.04.1 LTS

what can I do to see what's wrong ? its seems like gliches are getting more and more numerus I'm afraid it'll do bad damage

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 and am trying to update to 20.04.1 LTS
what can I do to see what's wrong ? its seems like gliches are getting more and more numerus I'm afraid it'll do bad damage

```
l@l-laptop:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for l: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

l@l-laptop:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

l@l-laptop:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.

l@l-laptop:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for l: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:4 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Hit:7 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease    
Get:8 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:9 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 1s (332 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

When I try to reboot it it shows black screen with _ at the top forever

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqhLo.png)

Comment: Screenshot: The update offered is 22.04.1, not 20.04.1. Big, big difference. It's unclear if you accepted the release-upgrade. If so, it's unclear if the release-upgrade completed without error. Your 'glitches' might be as simple as a video card driver update for your new kernel -- check your Software & Updates control panel. Also, please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: sorry for that. I need to get it up and running normally as fast as possible. I'm in my exam session rn so I can't really afford any time :( I should probably be looking up troubleshooting right after though.

Comment: What should-I be looking for in my software & updates panel ? I

Comment: if accepting the release-update means I cliqued upgrade then yes. But it is unclear as to whether that actually did it, because it still gives me the update offer

Comment: Your `apt update` output reflects a 20.04 (not 22.04) system...with several non-Ubuntu additions. Random non-Ubuntu sources are not supported by us, and are a frequent cause of breakage. If you want a *fast* solution (maybe 2 hours), then backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu. When you want to learn troubleshooting, then start reviewing your logs -- developers WANT you to know about problems. If you don't have time to troubleshoot, then it's not clear if we will be able to help you with your booting problem

Comment: thank you for your clear answers. I'll be sure to learn to understand logs as soon as I have free time. Until then I think I'm gonna have to reinstall ubuntu